# VS 2010 turning on camera but only shows grey window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

I'm new at this but have been doing my share of reading and trying different setups to help narrow down the problem! Any help tp get me past this road block would be much appreciated.

Currently I'm running: Win 7 Ultimate, Visual C++ 2010 Express, OpenCV 2.2.0, and a Microsoft - LifeCam Studio Webcam - Silver 1080p HD.

I'm getting no Build errors and when I run the program my camera comes on (blue light indicating it being on) and the screen pops up that i thought should show my camera feed but instead its just a grey box with nothing inside. The below code I thought would help narrow down the problem but I'm at a loss.

```
int main()
{
CvCapture *webcam = NULL;
webcam = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
if(webcam!=NULL)
  {
   IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame(webcam);
   cvShowImage("WEBCAM_TEST",frame);
   cvWaitKey(0);
   return 0;
  }
else
   {
     std::cout<<"CAMERA NOT DETECTED"<<std::endl;
     return 0;
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm using 64 bit OS if it maters!

Answer (score 3):

your code is sometimes showing a black image and sometimes shows the correct image on my system(Windows 7 64 VS2010 OpenCV 2.4.3)... however, when I put it in a loop for non-stop streaming the image is ok...so just modify your code slightly and try...

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    CvCapture *webcam = NULL;
    webcam = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);

    if(webcam!=NULL)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame(webcam);
            cvShowImage("WEBCAM_TEST",frame);
            cvWaitKey(20);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"CAMERA NOT DETECTED"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same problem! http://tinypic.com/r/35chbnk/6 Would you suggest moving to a newer version or working on this one?

Comment: can you access the cam with some other webcam softwares?...ya you can try the OpenCV 2.4.3...http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.3/OpenCV-2.4.3.exe/download

Comment: I'm going to try an update though I am not confident in this fixing the problem

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV if you get frame just after creating camera capture usually it's grey. All you have to do is just get next frame or wait before getting first frame. This code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) 
        return -1;

    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("01",1);

    //cap >> frame;   //option 1
    //waitKey(5000);   //option 2
    cap >> frame;
    imshow("01", frame);
    int key = waitKey(30);
    return 0;
}
```

will show grey frame, but if you uncomment option 1 or option 2 - it will work fine.